# Quoted printable - use MailMessage or create own logic

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking into the whole quoted-printable methodology and I'm wondering whether it is worth writing my own logic or whether to use the MailMessage that is including in the .Net Framework?

I have seen that MailMessage already has a quoted-printable method, but am not 100% on it's workings, which is why I'm thinking of writing my own logic.  Has anyone used the MailMessage quoted-printable method?  Is it worth me trying to create my own logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used MailMessage before and it has never caused me any trouble. However I have not used quoter-printable encoding. That being said if you set the `IsBodyHtml` to false it does seem to encode to quoted-printable. Alternatively you might try MailBee which extends the logic in MailMessage and has a number of encoding methods. They have a free trial which you might try. If neither of these work (which I could think is a very remote possibility) you could write your own logic but, I would try these other solutions first.

[MailBee](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/)

Comment: @Tim C: Thanks for the link to MailBee.  Looks interesting.